# Getting to the method in another class with List Object In constructor

Tags: java, android

How can i call answer method from Question class if i have the List Object in the constructor. It wont let me create the object without passing the List.
Calling Question question; and then this.question.answer crashes the app.

Comment: When you are referring to the `theAnswer` method, do you mean the method `public int answer() {`? your question is unclear

Comment: try the following, Question question = new Question(your_list);
question.answer();

Comment: sorry yes i refer to the answer method

Comment: in your answer method you call `toString`. in `toString` you need to list of stuff. So what result would you expect if you don't pass the list of stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create multiple constructor of class , which is called **constructor overloading**

```
public class Question {

private List<Object> list;

public Question(List<Object> list) {
this.list = list;
}
public Question() {
//do nothing
}

@Override
public String toString() {
String str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    str += list.get(i).toString() + " ";
}
return str;
}


public int answer() {
int theAnswer = (int) calculationl(this.toString());
System.out.println("The correct answer answer is " + theAnswer);
return theAnswer;
}}
```

Now you can instantiate **Question** class object from other  any other class without passing list object as

```
Question mQuestion= new Question();
int answer= mQuestion.answer();
```

Comment: doing it like this just closes the application

Comment: can you put code snippet here , so that i can have a look on it, may be i can help you in any way

Comment: i have added pert of the code where im trying to access answer method

Comment: are you getting any error ? put your stack trace here. One more thing i would like to ask , are you storing String objects inside the list , if you are then  you can change part of your code to as below:

Comment: private List<String> list;

public Question(List<String> list) {
this.list = list;
}
public Question() {
//do nothing
}

@Override
public String toString() {
String str = "";
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    str += list.get(i) + " ";
}
return str;
}

Answer (score 1):

Here,  no default constructor getting generated if you define an explicit constructor.

Write your own constructor ,

```
public Question() {
     System.out.println("empty constructor");
}
```